# array_map to simplify array, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, array-map

I have a function which returns an array of arrays when querying a table, each 'subarray' is a row in the table, now I want to create a 'fetchColumn' function to transform my resulting array from this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'column' => 'value'
    )
    [1] => Array(
        'column' => 'value'
    )
    [2] => Array(
        'column' => 'value'
    )
)
```

Into this:

```
Array(
    [0]=>value
    [1]=>value
    [2]=>value
)
```

Here is the function:

```
public static function fetchColumn($column)
    {
        $callback = function($value){
            return $value[$column];
        };        
        return array_map($callback,$array); // $array exists
    }
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't importing `$column` into your lambda:

```
$callback = function($value) use ($column) {
    return $value[$column];
};
```

*Edit* This assumes that you are calling the function `fetchColumn('column')`, and that `$array` really *does* exist within the context of `fetchColumn`. In your code, it doesn't...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, I haven't use that feature that much.